# Windows phone (IE 10) won't play html5 video (through redirection)

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, http-headers, html5-video

I have an issue with HTML5 video occurring on Windows Phone 8.0 (IE 10). The exact model I can manually reproduce it on is a *Nokia Lumia 521*.

So I have an HTML5 video on my page:

```
<video poster="http://cdn.example.com/img.png" controls>
    <source src="http://example.com/proxy">
</video>
```

At this point, the video won't play and the poster image won't show.

The poster image is a direct link to our CDN. The `source` `src` is pointing to a proxy on our server who'll redirect to a video resource on our CDN. Here are the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 22 Apr 2015 00:22:59 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: private
Location: http://cdn.example.com/resource.mp4
Vary: User-Agent
```

For some reason, if I load the mp4 directly in Windows Phone, it'll open the video app and play the content correctly.

It looks like something is going wrong when redirecting the video source through a 302.

---

You can reproduce this issue on yelp http://m.yelp.com/biz_photos/tropisue%C3%B1o-san-francisco-3?select_video=DoP8vwCSm2AcTp3RvBwybg

Comment: Since the file type can't be inferred from the proxy src, you might try adding a type attribute to the source. Like this: <source src='http://example.com/proxy' type="video/mp4">.

Comment: @TimHayes That did work. Mind posting as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file type can't be inferred from the proxy's src extension, you might try adding a type attribute to the source. Like this:

```
<video poster="http://cdn.example.com/img.png" controls>
    <source src='example.com/proxy' type="video/mp4">
</video>
```